# How to increment counters based on a column value being fixed in a Window?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I have a dataset that, over time, indicates the region where certain users were located. From this dataset I want to calculate the number of nights that they spent at each location. By "spending the night" I mean: take the last location seen of a user until 23h59 of a certain day; if all observed locations from that user until 05:00 the next day, or the first one after that if there is none yet, match the last of the previous day, that's a night spent at that location.

```
| Timestamp| User| Location|
|1462838468|49B4361512443A4DA...|1|
|1462838512|49B4361512443A4DA...|1|
|1462838389|49B4361512443A4DA...|2|
|1462838497|49B4361512443A4DA...|3|
|1465975885|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|1|
|1457723815|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|1|
|1457897289|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|2|
|1457899229|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|11|
|1457972626|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|9| 
|1458062553|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|9|
|1458241825|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|9|
|1458244457|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|9|
|1458412513|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|6|
|1458412292|405C238E25FE0B9E7...|6|
|1465197963|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|6|
|1465202192|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|6|
|1465923817|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|5|
|1465923766|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|2|
|1465923748|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|2|
|1465923922|6E9E0581E2A032FD8...|2|
```

I'm guessing I need to use Window functions here, and I've used PySpark for other things in the past, but I'm a bit at a loss as to where to start here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in the end you do need to have a function that takes a series of events and outputs nights spent... something like (example just to get the idea):

```
def nights_spent(location_events):
    # location_events is a list of events that have time and location

    location_events = sort_by_time(location_events)

    nights = []

    prev_event = None
    for event in location_events[1:]:
        if prev_location is not None:
            if next_day(prev_event.time, event.time) \
               and same_location(prev_event.location, event.location):
                # TODO: How do you handle when prev_event
                # and event are more than 1 day apart?  
                nights.append(prev_location)

        prev_location = location

   return nights
```

Then, I think that a good first approach is to first group by user so that you get all events (with location and time) for a given user.

Then you can feed that list of events to the function above, and you'll have all the `(user, nights_spent)` rows in an RDD.

So, in general, the RDD would look something like:

```
nights_spent_per_user = all_events.map(lambda x => (x.user, [(x.time, x.location)])).reduce(lambda a, b: a + b).map(x => (x[0], nights_spent(x[1])))
```

Hope that helps to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I need to wrap my head around this but it seems like a very good start.